# htaccess rewrite rule to subdirectory and then hide the url?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a subdomain called sub.domain2.com which I want to point to domain1.com/folder/

I have set up an A record to point sub.domain2.com to domain1.com and a rewrite rule to the point the subdomain to the subdirectory:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} sub\.domain2\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://sub.domain2.com/folder/$1 [L]
```

However I don't want the subdirectory /folder/ showing in the URL which it currently is?

Thanks
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `http://.../` because it will force external redirect.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} sub\.domain2\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) /folder/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you set DOCUMENT_ROOT of `sub.domain2.com` to `domain1.com/folder` in your apache config.